# Sorting an Array of string which contains integers and characters

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

- I read 5 elements from a file.
- My file //  H4,C8,HJ,C9,D10,D5,DK,D2,S7,DJ,SK,H3,H6
- BTW these are playing cards. I am ignoring the first character.
- my first 5 sorted list is supposed to look like this - HJ, D10, C9, C8, H4

  ```
  while(getline(inputFile, val, ','))
  {
      stringstream ss(val);
      while(ss.good() && i < 5)
      {
          ss >> myArray[i];
          i++;

      }
  ```
- How can I sort my array in ascending order..
- Or do I need to sort before I store data string in my Array?

Comment: A. Use a vector B. Use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+sort&oq=c%2B%2B+sort&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.1151j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Doesn't [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) work for you?

Comment: I am not supposed to use vector.. - scohe001.

Comment: @user8515431 _"I am not supposed to use vector."_ =8O Why?? Well, no worry `std::sort` would work regardless.

Comment: It's a good idea to place assignment restrictions into the question. Otherwise you rack up a load of "Just use `std::XYZ`" answers. Note that in the real world they are usually the right answer, but they aren't all that useful to you as a student.

Comment: Two good ways to handle this: Insert the data into your list in the correct order (search the list for where the item needs to go, then place it. Read up on Binary Search) or insert unordered and sort. If you must write your own sort, Wikipedia has a great page on Quicksort. I recommend the Hoare partition because I find it easier to write correctly.

Answer (score 1):

here is the small example how you sort your cards (you have also to think about error handling it, didn't implement it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int getCardRange(const std::string& card)
{
    switch(card[1])
    {
        case '2': return 2;
        case '3': return 3;
        case '4': return 4;
        case '5': return 5;
        case '6': return 6;
        case '7': return 7;
        case '8': return 8;
        case '9': return 9;
        case '1': return 10;
        case 'J': return 11;
        case 'Q': return 12;
        case 'K': return 13;
        case 'A': return 14;
    }
    return -1; // error
}

bool compare(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
    return getCardRange(a) > getCardRange(b);
}

int main()
{
    std::string myArray[13] = {"H4","C8","HJ","C9","D10","D5","DK","D2","S7","DJ","SK","H3","H6"};
    // sort using a lambda expression 
    std::sort(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), compare);

    for(auto card : myArray)
    {
        std::cout << card << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::sort  with vectors (you can read more [in the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort))

It takes as input an array like this:

`std::sort(cards.begin(), cards.end());`

Comment: Just saw that you can't use `std::sort` . In that case, I think after you trim the first character you can assign the letters a value J = 11 and so on, and after it's just sorting numbers in ascending or descending order.

Comment: _Arrays_ don't have a `begin()` or `end()` function. There are `std::begin()` and `std::end()` though.

Comment: Yup yup, I meant that he could use it with vectors.

Comment: I can not use vector.. Is there any other way to sort my string array.. Thanks

Comment: You can use `std::sort()` with any random-access iterator, which includes pointers into an array, eg: `int myArray[5]; std::sort(myArray, myArray+5);`  In C++11 and later, `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are overloaded for fixed arrays: `std::sort(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to have vector or array. If you are not allowed to use vector then create an array by first reading the array and counting the number of items (`count`). Create an array based on that size, then read the file again and set the array items:

```
string str;
int count = 0;
while(getline(file, str, ','))
    count++;

string *sarray = new string[count];

file.clear();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
int i = 0;
while(getline(file, str, ','))
{
    //trim spaces if any
    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(' '));
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1);

    sarray[i] = str;
    i++;
    if(i == count)
        break;
}
```

To sort the values, break the string in to two parts. For example break H4 in to `H` and `4`. Then run a comparison. The following uses lambda sort. Maybe you want to change it to something similar to the other answer.

```
std::sort(sarray, sarray + count, [](string a, string b)
{
    //save the first character
    char chA = a[0];
    char chB = b[0];

    //remove the first character
    a.erase(0, 1);
    b.erase(0, 1);

    if(a == "J") a = "11";
    if(a == "Q") a = "12";
    if(a == "K") a = "13";
    if(a == "A") a = "14";

    if(b == "J") b = "11";
    if(b == "Q") b = "12";
    if(b == "K") b = "13";
    if(b == "A") b = "14";

    //convert to integer
    int v1 = stoi(a);
    int v2 = stoi(b);

    //if the two cards have the same values...
    if(v2 == v1) return chA > chB;

    return v1 > v2;
});
```

For cleanup:

```
delete[]sarray;
```

Note, you may wish to add exception handling for `stoi`